# I am performing SVD on a matrix in Python and MATLAB. SVD's "V" values across columns are same in both (ignoring sign) apart from last column. Why?

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, pca, svd

SVD on the original `matrix` produces same results in both Python and MATLAB (ignoring the signs). However, when I center the matrix, the last column of `V` differs between Python and MATLAB.

MATLAB Code:

```
[~,~,pc_nc]=svd(matrix,'econ');
matrixCenter=matrix-repmat(mean(matrix),size(matrix,1),1);
[~,~,pc_c]=svd(matrixCenter,'econ');
```

Python Code:

```
_, _, pc_nc = np.linalg.svd(matrix, full_matrices=False)
pc_nc = pc_nc.transpose()
matrixCenter = matrix - np.matlib.repmat(np.mean(matrix, 0), np.size(matrix, 0), 1)
_, _, pc_c = np.linalg.svd(matrixCenter, full_matrices=False)
pc_c = pc_c.transpose()
```

`pc_nc` in both Python and MATLAB is same. `pc_c` differs on the last column.
The `matrix` can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bLrz0EFCuon7YXS_IY1J9Va6u0MSASYZlLJVQ4TN95A/edit#gid=0

I tried using `scipy.linalg.svd()` but to no avail. How can I get the same results across all the columns on the centered matrix? Please help.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. `matrix` needed rounding off.